# INR currency format

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to show currency format like these, how can we show.

```
₹1
₹10
₹100
₹1,000
₹10,000
₹1,00,000
......
```

Comment: Do you have any existing code ?

Comment: Note: Indian rupee follows the different format (especially on specifying the comma between numbers). The solution, what you have accepted is going to append the '₹' symbol before the USD formatted currency value.

Comment: @ Code Ninja .. You Got any Solution or Suggestion ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76215289/14344959

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### AngularJS

In HTML

```
{{ currency_expression | currency : symbol : fractionSize}}
```

for example

```
{{amount | currency:"₹":0}}
```

AngularJS docs [Currency Pipe](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency)

#### Angular 2+

```
{{amount | currency:'INR':'symbol-narrow':'4.2-2'}}
```

you can also refer [Currency Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe)

Comment: This doesn't represent the comma as per indian currency standard. It just remove the fraction from the number.

Comment: @NiralMunjariya It does :), how did you test :O

Comment: it works with v1.3.0 check [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bFR9JGTUAxvlAlDj6Ybu?p=preview)

Comment: FYI: http://jsfiddle.net/gascpt2x/, I've used 1.3.0 here but still it doesn't seem to be working as I expect.

Comment: It's acceptable according [Indian Number System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system).

Comment: You need your own custom filter if it's not as your expectation.

Comment: I know and that's what I am saying, this answer doesn't represent the format specified in the question.

Comment: answer is half right it should be  Eg :in format 1,22,33,233.00 And not 12,233,233.00. So down voting

Comment: This is not the correct answer. Angular4 throws an error.

Comment: The Indian numbering system is different from it is followed internationally.
We have 1 Lakh for 100 Thousand
whereas internationally 1 Million for 1000 Thousand.

Comment: For view it is fine but what if I want to pass only number no currency symbol in ts file ?

Answer (score 16):

Indian rupee follows different format compare to US currency; So, don't use default angular currency filter to format Indian Rupees

**Custom INR Currency Filter**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('indexCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.amount = 10000000.33;
});

app.filter('INR', function () {        
    return function (input) {
        if (! isNaN(input)) {
            var currencySymbol = '₹';
            //var output = Number(input).toLocaleString('en-IN');   <-- This method is not working fine in all browsers!           
            var result = input.toString().split('.');

            var lastThree = result[0].substring(result[0].length - 3);
            var otherNumbers = result[0].substring(0, result[0].length - 3);
            if (otherNumbers != '')
                lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
            var output = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree;
            
            if (result.length > 1) {
                output += "." + result[1];
            }            

            return currencySymbol + output;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="indexCtrl">
    Input: <input type="text" ng-model="amount">
    <h3>{{amount | INR}}</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how to apply for input type="text"

Comment: This should be marked as answer as it actually gives which is asked.

Comment: I think you should add one more condition `if (! isNaN(input) && input != 0)` for avoiding multiple '0'

Answer (score 8):

Just use INR in currency filter

```
{{product.product_cost | currency:'INR':true}}
```

Comment: This does not format currency in desired format.

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is looking for the same in Angular 2, then here is solution:

1. Create custom pipe
2. Use in your HTML pipe code

**Step 1**: Create file indianCurrency.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'indianCurrency'})
export class IndianCurrency implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, args: string[]): any {
     
        if (! isNaN(value)) {
            var currencySymbol = '₹';
            //var output = Number(input).toLocaleString('en-IN');   <-- This method is not working fine in all browsers!           
            var result = value.toString().split('.');

            var lastThree = result[0].substring(result[0].length - 3);
            var otherNumbers = result[0].substring(0, result[0].length - 3);
            if (otherNumbers != '')
                lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
            var output = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree;
            
            if (result.length > 1) {
                output += "." + result[1];
            }            

            return currencySymbol + output;
        }
     
  }
}
```

Declare in app.module.ts

```
 declarations: [
  .....,
    IndianCurrency
  ],
```

**Step 2**: Use in your HTML

```
{{amount | indianCurrency}}
```

Comment: Getting error Angular 12 - `Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.`

Comment: Change transform(value: number, args: string[]) to transform(value: number)

Comment: Just edited answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can make a filter using `toLocaleString` like :

```
Number(data).toLocaleString('en-IN', { style: 'currency', currency: 'INR', maximumFractionDigits: 0})
```

Filter example :

```
.filter('IndianCurrency', function() {
    return function(data) {
        if (null != data) {
            return Number(data).toLocaleString('en-IN', { style: 'currency', currency: 'INR', maximumFractionDigits: 0});
        } else {
            return Number(0).toLocaleString('en-IN', { style: 'currency',currency: 'INR', maximumFractionDigits: 0});
        }
    };
});
```

Usage :

```
{{ rent | IndianCurrency }}
```

Answer (score 5):

Indian currency short like if you want to currency view like **₹ 2.5 Lakh, ₹ 3 Cr,  ₹12 Lakh etc** then use below Pipe.
It will work

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'pricePipe'
})
export class PricePipePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: number, args: string[]): any {

    if (! isNaN(value)) {
        var currencySymbol = '₹';
        if (value == null) {
          return '';
      }
      var InrRSOut = value;
      InrRSOut = Math.round(InrRSOut);
      var RV = "";
      if (InrRSOut > 0 && InrRSOut < 1000) {
          RV = InrRSOut.toString();
      }
      else if (InrRSOut >= 1000 && InrRSOut < 10000) {
          RV = InrRSOut.toString();
      }
      else if (InrRSOut >= 10000 && InrRSOut < 100000) {
          var f1 = InrRSOut.toString().substring(0, 2);
          var f2 = InrRSOut.toString().substring(2, 5);
          RV = f1 + "," + f2;

      }
      else if (InrRSOut >= 100000 && InrRSOut < 1000000) {
          var f1 = InrRSOut.toString().substring(0, 1);
          var f2 = InrRSOut.toString().substring(1, 3);
          if (f2 == "00") {
              RV = f1 + " Lacs";
          }
          else {
              RV = f1 + "." + f2 + " Lacs";
          }
      }
      else if (InrRSOut >= 1000000 && InrRSOut < 10000000) {
          var f1 = InrRSOut.toString().substring(0, 2);
          var f2 = InrRSOut.toString().substring(2, 4);
          if (f2 == "00") {
              RV = f1 + " Lacs";
          }
          else {
              RV = f1 + "." + f2 + " Lacs";
          }
      }
      else if (InrRSOut >= 10000000 && InrRSOut < 100000000) {
          var f1 = InrRSOut.toString().substring(0, 1);
          var f2 = InrRSOut.toString().substring(1, 3);
          if (f2 == "00") {
              RV = f1 + " Cr";
          }
          else {
              RV = f1 + "." + f2 + " Cr";
          }
      }
      else if (InrRSOut >= 100000000 && InrRSOut < 1000000000) {
          var f1 = InrRSOut.toString().substring(0, 2);
          var f2 = InrRSOut.toString().substring(2, 4);
          if (f2 == "00") {
              RV = f1 + " Cr";
          }
          else {
              RV = f1 + "." + f2 + " Cr";
          }
      }
      else if (InrRSOut >= 1000000000 && InrRSOut < 10000000000) {
          var f1 = InrRSOut.toString().substring(0, 3);
          var f2 = InrRSOut.toString().substring(3, 5);
          if (f2 == "00") {
              RV = f1 + " Cr";
          }
          else {
              RV = f1 + "." + f2 + " Cr";
          }
      }
      else if (InrRSOut >= 10000000000) {
          var f1 = InrRSOut.toString().substring(0, 4);
          var f2 = InrRSOut.toString().substring(6, 8);
          if (f2 == "00") {
              RV = f1 + " Cr";
          }
          else {
              RV = f1 + "." + f2 + " Cr";
          }
      }
      else {
          RV = InrRSOut.toString();
      }
      return currencySymbol + RV;
    }

}

}
```

**In HTML Use like**

```
{{ 125000000 | pricePipe }}
```

**Output**

```
₹12.50 Cr
```

Answer (score 4):

To print the rupee symbol(**₹**), try like this:

```
{{price | currency:"&#8377;"}}
```

For more formatting, refer [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency).

Comment: @vijay, I am unable to get you? Can you please explain.

Comment: this question includes 2 questions.1st : symbol 2nd : Formatting.   For More infor look at @codeninja.sj answer it includes both

Comment: @vijay, the `currency` filter does the formatting on its own. You can check. :)

Comment: @vijay, here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/U5UCqzbiLVQEZhqea6Ls?p=preview) link for the same.

Comment: rohit still that plunkr is in US currency Format Not INR format.You can see the question its saying INR it should be ₹1,00,000 AND NOT ₹111,000,000,BY default angular gives us currency format

Answer (score 2):

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'customCurrency'
})
export class CustomCurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: number, isSymbol: string, decPointer: string, isPrefix: boolean): string {

    if (!isNaN(value)) {
       var formatted_value;
      var currencyText = isSymbol;
      if (currencyText == '₹') {
        // for Indian number system
        formatted_value = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN').format(value)
      }
      else {
        formatted_value = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(value)
      }
      return currencyText + ' ' + formatted_value;
    }
  }

}
```

HTML

`<div>{{ 10000000 | customCurrency:'₹':'1.0':false}}</div>`

Answer (score 2):

I believe the `currency pipe` will solve this problem

Note: **Syntax** for digit param in the symbol is -> `"numberOfInteger:minimumFractions-maxFractions"`

> **Input:** 
>   {{1499 | currency:'INR':'symbol':'1.0'}}
>
> **Output:** 
>   ₹1,499

**Explanation** -> `'1.0'` means currency pipe will display at least 1 digits and no decimal.

Let me provide you with another example:

> **Input:** 
>   {{99 | currency:'INR':'symbol':'3.2-2'}}
>
> **Output:** 
>   ₹099.00

**Explanation** -> `'3.2-2'` means currency pipe will display at least 3 digits and the decimal point minimum 2 fractions & maximum 2 fractions are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
var x=1000;
x=x.toString();
var lastThree = x.substring(x.length-3);
var otherNumbers = x.substring(0,x.length-3);
if(otherNumbers != '')
    lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
var res = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree;

alert(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

For display amount with two digits after decimal ...

Try this:

```
var num=1234.567;
 var ans= num.toLocaleString('en-IN',{ style: 'currency', currency: "INR",minimumFractionDigits:2,maximumFractionDigits:2 });

//output
//₹ 1,234.57
```

Comment: Thanks, Works for me to create custom filter:

module.filter('formatINR', function () {
        return function (input) {
            if (angular.isUndefined(input) || input === null || input == 'null') {
                return '';
            }
            return input.toLocaleString('en-IN', { currency: "INR", minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 });
        }
    });

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late, but you can just use https://osrec.github.io/currencyFormatter.js/ which handles

Then all you need is:

```
// Outputs ₹ 25,34,234.00
OSREC.CurrencyFormatter.format(2534234, { currency: 'INR' });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can format currency in INR with using pipe and even removing decimal value (i.e Paise) like

```
{{bal.walletamt | currency:"₹ " : false : '2.0-0'}}
```

this code will work for ionic3 also

Answer (score 1):

```
{{myobject.price | currency:'INR'}}
```

> If you don't need last decimal value then you can use number pipe with

```
₹{{myobject.price | number}}
```

> If you don't need last decimal value but you want to use the inbuilt
>   currency pipe functionality, then you can create a custom pipe for
>   currency or you can create a split pipe and use with currency

```
Ex: {{myobject.price  | currency:'INR' | custSplit:".":"0"}}
```

> Note: custSplit- It is a custom pipe it split the string what ever we
>   pass (here- ".") and take the index what we need(Here- "0"Index).

For more on pipe, read [angular 2+ doc](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe)

Answer (score 1):

Use combination of comma separator pipe and  Custom INR Currency PIPE

In HTML

**1.first use comma separator pipe .**

**2.After that use custom pipe** **INRpipe**

{{ currency_expression | number: ' ' : 'en-IN' | INRpipe }}

Pipe.ts

transform(value: string): string {

```
if (!value) {
  return null;
}

return `₹${value}`; // this line will only solve your problem
```

**Below is optional**

**/**
if you want to add two decimal point in currency
**/**

then follow this way.

if (value.includes('.')) {

```
  return `₹${value}`;

}
```

return `₹${value}.00`;

}

Answer (score 0):

Just add **currency** filter like this.

```
 {{object.price | currency:"INR":true}}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the digits before last three.
2. Replace the rest of the digits with `prefix.replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",")`
3. Combine the above section with this modified prefix

Complete explanation on why this regex places commas at the right place is is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294959/how-does-b-d3-d-g-work-for-adding-comma-on-numbers).

Answer (score 0):

In your example you have set the currency being displayed but you may still using the en-US locale to process the currency value. You also need to change the locale to en-IN. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdh8to?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

This solution works, Angular is providing this by default - [https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe#:~:text=is%20undefined.-,locale,-string](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe#:%7E:text=is%20undefined.-,locale,-string)

Credits to the comment owner - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/40350#issuecomment-756733642

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:** for Transforms a number to a INR currency string we can achieve using [Angular's Currency Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe)

Step 1: import & register locales Data

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common'; // import this
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import enIN from "@angular/common/locales/en-IN"; // // & also import this one


@Component({
  selector: 'app-price',
  templateUrl: './price.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./price.component.scss']
})
export class PriceComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
    registerLocaleData(enIN); // for register locales add this line
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Now, you can use it (curreny pipe) in your HTML for inr curreny Transformation.

```
{{ 100000 | currency: 'INR':undefined:undefined:'en-IN' }} // ₹1,00,000.00

{{ 100000 | currency: 'USD':undefined:undefined:'en-US' }} // $100,000.00
```

[see live demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cojz7p)

[another example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unvyxy)

credit goes to this [answer's auther](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73921124/14344959) [I got solution about locale option (en-IN)]

---

**Method 2:** we can also convert number into locale currency format using Intnl.NumberFormat API [see MDN Documenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/formatToParts)

```
function tranformIntoLocaleCurrency(price, currencyCode, localeCode) {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat(localeCode, { style: 'currency', currency: currencyCode }).formatToParts(price).map(val => val.value).join('');
}

console.log( tranformIntoLocaleCurrency(100000, "INR", "en-IN")); // ₹1,00,000.00
console.log(tranformIntoLocaleCurrency(100000, "USD", "en-US")); // $100,000.00
```

see [live working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w697xfoh/)

Answer (score 0):

Import the Indian locale data into your Angular module:

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import localeIn from '@angular/common/locales/en-IN';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';

// Register the locale data for 'en-IN'
registerLocaleData(localeIn);
```

Provide the Indian locale in your module's provider array:

```
@NgModule({
  // ... (other module properties)
  providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-IN' }],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You can use it like this for crores, lacs formatting

```
{{ amount | currency:'INR':'symbol-narrow':'1.0-2':'en-IN' }}
```

Answer (score -1):

In angular, Create a custom filter like this

```
myApp.filter('ic', function()
{
   return function(value)
   {
       return '₹ ' + value;
   }
});
```

And then you can `{{data|number|ic}}`

Answer (score -1):

You can use this : `{{amount:| currency:"₹"}}` or you can use hex code for `"₹"`

Input: `{{3*100000000 | currency:"₹"}}`

Output: `₹300,000,000.00`

Answer (score -1):

If "amount" is your variable containing the number to converted to INR format, use one of the approaches given below in your html code -

1.
{{ amount | currency:'INR':true}}

Result: ₹150,000.00

2.
{{ amount | currency:'INR':true}}

Result: INR150,000.00

3.
{{ amount.toLocaleString('en-IN')}}

Result: 1,50,000