# Angular JS currency filter showing same format for ₹ and $

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters, currency-formatting

I have a scenario where i should be able to format the currency dynamically. I'm using angular currency filter.
Here is my code

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="costCtrl">
    <p>Rupee: {{ price | currency : "&#8377;"}}</p>
    <p>Dollar: {{ price | currency : "$"}}</p>
 </div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('costCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.price = 5800000;
});
```

In the above code i'm using two types of currencies RUPEE and DOLLAR but it is showing same for the both currencies.

here is my output for above code

RUPEE :   ₹5,800,000 
DOLLAR:   $5,800,000

below is my expected output

RUPEE :   ₹58,00,000 
DOLLAR:   $5,800,000

please help me in this. Thanks in advance

I need a generic solution for all currency formats not only for indian rupee. Like €1.234.567,89 EUR
Here EUR currency format is different they use . as thousand separators and , as decimal separators.
Can i have any suggestions for implementing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INR currency format in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598765/inr-currency-format-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own `currency convertor`, below is a working `fiddle`:

```
.filter('currency', function() {
    var defaultCurrency = '$';
    return function(input, currencySymbol) {
      var out = "";
      currencySymbol = currencySymbol || defaultCurrency;
        switch(currencySymbol) {
            case '₹':
                out = 67 * input;
                break;

            default: 
                out = input;
        }

      return out + ' ' + currencySymbol;
    }
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bvgkwczd/

Comment: That's now what the OP wants. You are literally converting from USD to INR. He instead wants to format is as per the conventions used in India. It's about the commas in the amount

Comment: Thanks for your response. I Know the currency conversion but the above question i'm referring to is the currency formatting i.e, where the comma position etc..

Comment: @user2451830: This link should help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598765/inr-currency-format-in-angular sorry my mistake... may be i took the question in different perspective..

Comment: @Thalaivar thanks for the link. Can i have any suggestion on how to implement a generic filter which will do all the currency formats