# Currency number Format

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to format the amount I get from my API into the locale-specific format.

In console:

```
Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN').format(450000) // "4,50,000"
```

In an Angular 2 component template:

```
{{ Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN').format(450000) }} // Cannot read property 'NumberFormat' of undefined

{{ 450000 | currency:'INR':true }} // ₹450,000.00
```

Is there a way I can get `₹4,50,000.00` without specifying the delimiters explicitly (and be able to change the locale string `'en-IN'` to `'en-US'` to update).

Comment: Have your tried to add property `Intl = Intl` in your component?

Comment: I do not think it is possible, see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35599657/2562935) if that might help you

Answer (score 8):

Just use the currency pipe to keep things simple. Assuming your variable in your template is called `myamount`. Then just access it with

```
@Component({
  selector: 'currency-pipe',
  template: `<div>
    <p>Amount: {{myamount | currency:'USD':true}}</p>
  </div>`
})
export class CurrencyPipeComponent {
  myamount: number = 0.259;
}
```

Source and more information about the currency pipe: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/CurrencyPipe-pipe.html

You might want also to set the default culture: [How to set locale in DatePipe in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904683/how-to-set-locale-in-datepipe-in-angular2)

In the cookbook you may find more information about i18n and how to change it at runtime:

```
<script>
  // Get the locale id somehow
  document.locale = 'fr';

  // Map to the text plugin
  System.config({
    map: {
      text: 'systemjs-text-plugin.js'
    }
  });

  // Launch the app
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

Source: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html#!#merge-with-the-jit-compiler

Answer (score 0):

Amount Separted by Common:

Use this code in your html template

```
{{ separteAmount(450000)}}
```

and

Make a function in your `.ts` file

```
separteAmount(Number){
   return Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN').format(Number)
}
```