# AngularJS: Format currencies separated by commas dynamically using currency/country codes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to display amounts of the different currencies in my grid ( Comma separated format). But all amounts are coming as same format

For Example:

Currently I am getting this

```
USD- 1,234,567
INR- 1,234,567
```

But I want like this. Dynamically using currency code

```
USD- 1,234,567
INR- 12,34,567
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y6fhcme3/1/

Help me!!

Answer (score 0):

You should add custom pipe for Indian Rupees:
http://jsfiddle.net/4zb2p91d/
as mentioned in this  post [INR currency format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598765/inr-currency-format)

```
.filter('INR', function () {        
    return function (input, code) {
        if (! isNaN(input)) {
            var currencySymbol = '₹';
            //var output = Number(input).toLocaleString('en-IN');   <-- This method is not working fine in all browsers!           
            var result = input.toString().split('.');

            var lastThree = result[0].substring(result[0].length - 3);
            var otherNumbers = result[0].substring(0, result[0].length - 3);
            if (otherNumbers != '')
                lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
            var output = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree;

            if (result.length > 1) {
                output += "." + result[1];
            }            

            return currencySymbol + output;
        }
    }
});
```

and using:

```
<div ng-app="miniapp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">
            {{item.amount | INR : item.code }}
        </div>         
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But There are many currencies will come not only INR

Comment: you could check input parameters in filter and apply described converting only for currency with code 'INR'

Comment: Examples with checking input parameters you could use from answers above but keeps in mind that not all browsers support Number(input).toLocaleString('en-IN').

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs currency filter will not format the number based on currency. It only adds the prefix specified and also round off the number if fraction size is specified.

For formatting based on currency, you can use number.toLocaleString. Refer
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString for detailed usage.

For formatting INR you can use `value.toLocaleString('en-IN)`

Comment: Hi @Hari Prathap, I am getting only currency codes ( Like - INR, USD, JPY..), don't have locales. What to do in that case?

Comment: @NNR, I guess you should have a map for currency and locale in that case but I understand it is not scalable.