# how to convert number to Indian rupees format in angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

required to convert number to rupees format

I tried and get output like 222,555,555.0 but I actually need the output like 22,25,55,555.00

Comment: How do you do it? Show us the template.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [INR currency format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598765/inr-currency-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let x = 12345678

var result = x.toLocaleString('en-IN', {
maximumFractionDigits: 2,
minimumFractionDigits: 2,
});

console.log("result=",result)
result= 1,23,45,678.00

Comment: Nice so there is a vanilla JavaScript way to do this